# Lock Windows Slideshow for the Lock Screen

Tags: windows, lockscreen, group-policy, regedit

I want to disable the abbility to change the slideshow folder for the lockscreen.

I tried to disable it in the  [group policy editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTQST.png) but now i only cant switch between slideshow or image anymore.
The User [still can add Folders for the Slideshow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHmQN.png).

Is there any way to disable this?
thanks

setting reg key **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization NoChangingLockScreen 1**

enabled Slideshow with reg key:  **Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lock Screen SlideShowEnabled 1**